# Gap in body despite margin, padding 0

Tags: html, css

I am changing the design of a client's website. He gave me a template he got somewhere and I am kinda upgrading it. Now I got this big space in the top. My body is coming down by around 200px and I cannot figure out. The html is in top and all of sudden the body is got a gap. Padding 0 and margin 0.

The page is at http://imajination.in/00dev/planb/
Any help is appreciated

Comment: looks to me its okay give a screenshot and ofcourse the browser which in use by u

Comment: Post relevant code (in the question itself) and specify on which browser(s) the problem appears. Do not expect people to do basic debugging for you. Check that the code you post is valid. Note that the page you mention has 13 markup errors as reported by a validator.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela yep much more if minimised to mob screen and menu changes to dropdown style/dashboard style and if window maximised on after that page breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gap is because of the `margin-top` applied a div in body.

This is css code affecting the layout:

```
.home-box {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

Remove this `home-box` class from this line :

```
<div class="container home-box pos-center scroll-fade-effect">
```

Comment: This worked.. Thanks :) But I am curious to know how a div inside is affecting the body. Can you explain in

Comment: Its explained well on this link : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579000/why-margin-top-of-the-top-div-would-apply-to-body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579000/why-margin-top-of-the-top-div-would-apply-to-body).