# There is a gap at the top of my webpage

Tags: html, css, web

here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/optjhz2m/)
I have already tried a couple of different things such as `body { margin:0; padding:0;}` it doesn't work

```
body {
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 3000px;
}
```

Comment: can you help me to understand why you giving `max-width` and `height` in `body` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the header margin:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    /*margin: 20px 0;*/
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The space comes from this. Delete it.

Answer (score 0):

this is called [Margin Collapsing](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/)..
try replacing this..

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/optjhz2m/1/)
and refer this for [Detailed Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7579057/3164682)

Answer (score 0):

Add reset.css file to your webpage. ask google for reset.css

Answer (score 0):

```
 margin: 0px 20px 0 20px; or margin-top:-10px;
```

try this